# Can't parse json Data via YAJLiOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, yajl

At first i'm trying to access local file in my app folder:

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:
                                      [@"countries.json" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
```

result is always NULL

then i tried to check is file exists:

```
    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"countries.json"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
```

it doesn't exist, and i use following code to access my json file:

```
    NSString *data1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:data1];
```

it getting the file but when i try to parse it:

```
    NSDictionary *dict1 =[data2 yajl_JSON];
```

i getting an error:

```
    [NSConcreteData yajl_JSON]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6838d60
```

---

**My questions is next**:

- Is there any chance to convert NSData to NSConcreteData?
- Am i using the right approach to access data?

---

Api documentation - http://gabriel.github.com/yajl-objc/

Screenshot of my Xcode Build Phases:

[image]

Comment: i think that my main problem it that i using wrong approach to access data

Comment: Did you remember to #import <YAJL/YAJL.h> in your class?

Comment: Also, regarding NSConcreteData, see the answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113811/what-is-nsconcretedata-and-where-is-it-defined

Comment: yes, YAJLiOS/YAJL.h is imported

Comment: and i treat NSConcreteData like NSData but i suppose that YAJLiOS don't

Comment: @jonkroll How would an import prevent a runtime error?

Comment: The questions are: 1. Did you link against the YAJL library / sources? 2. Does YAJL actually provide a category on NSData offering a method called yajl_JSON?

Comment: 1.Yes 2.Yes (see the Api documentation in main question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the YAJL documentation the method you are trying to invoke does in fact exist.

That leaves only one option; you have not fully linked against the YAJL framework.

Make sure it shows up within the list of linked frameworks/libraries of your App target just like `CFNetwork.framework` shows up in my example.

[image]

Since the method you are trying to invoke is in fact part of a **category** on `NSData`, make sure you include `-ObjC` in your **Other Linker Flags**.

[image]

[From Apple's Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html).

> This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library
>   that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will
>   typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code
>   loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of
>   effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on
>   existing classes.

Comment: i's linked - http://s13.postimage.org/xwxtjiqh3/Screen_Shot_2012_04_29_at_2_19_41_AM.png (screenshot of my Xcode Build Phases)

Comment: Thanks! this works. At first i thought it would only work on the simulator, but it also works on real device!

Comment: The linker flag is tricky and a common pitfall when using custom/third party libraries that contain categories. Been there, got the Tshirt :D..