# What condition would cause an iVar to change its type?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have an iVar `NSMutableArray* _syncModels` and in the init method of my class I initialize it like `_syncModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];`

Throughout the class, I'm adding and removing objects from the array, but I never reinitialize `_syncModels`.

So I get this crash report that says `-[NSConcreteData filterUsingPredicate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x23c740c0`.

After symbolicating, the line that caused this crash is `[_syncModels filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (dataManagerFieldRecord = nil)"]];`

How in the world can `_syncModels` change from an `NSMutableArray` to an `NSConcreteData`?

This particular crash is rare, but we are getting more of these where some object gets discombobulated and is sent a message it can't handle.

We're targeting 6.1 under ARC.

**EDIT**

I figured out the problem...I was inadvertently adding `self` (which owns the reference to `_syncModels`) to a dispatch queue from `self`'s `dealloc` method...so this is a memory management problem...

Comment: First, take a look at [this other SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113811/what-is-nsconcretedata-and-where-is-it-defined) about NSConcreteData and class clusters (which is what NSMutableArray is). Then give us more information about what type of objects you are storing in `_syncModels`. Your bug is not really about NSConcreteData, but it very likely lies somewhere in the objects you are holding and the predicate you are creating.

Comment: @sosborn - `NSMutableArray` is not a class cluster of `NSConcreteData` is it?  The objects that I insert into this array are all of the same type and they have the property referenced in my predicate.  My unit tests pass every time.

Comment: My guess is that the NSConcreteData instance is actually referencing a property in one of the objects that you are collecting in your array. Is it possible that you have an object in there that doesn't respond to `dataManagerFieldRecord`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What condition would cause an iVar to change its type?

The only case I can imagine is that the programmer modifies its type in the source code and recompiles it.

What you mean is that **the object pointed to by the pointer stored in the ivar has been changed.** This is a typical memory management error, and it generally means that the object you expect to be there has already been deallocated prematurely (because you haven't kept enough references to it), then the runtime reused its underlying memory chunk when the creation of a new object was needed.

Comment: Yes...your bold statement is more accurate (and concise) than my question.  However, this particular iVar is private to the class and the particular method that caused the crash is also private.  The class is doing something internal to an internal object.  I don't understand at what point this object is being deallocated prematurely because I never change it once I alloc/init it in my class's init method.

Comment: @TReddy I don't see the relation. Don't "internal" objects need to be memory-managed just like "public" ones?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...I was trying to communicate that nothing else has a reference to this iVar except the owning class when I used the term "internal object".  So nothing else but this class can modify this object and this object will not get dealloc'ed until the class does.

Comment: @TReddy is an argument for one of your methods overriding your class variable? Check your warnings